# How to reverse each pair of fields separated by comma using one line sed command

Tags: shell

How to reverse each pair of fields separated by comma using one line sed command.

Sample input:

```
23,A,49,B,2,C
25,B,27,D,8,
```

Sample output:

```
A,23,B,49,C,2
B,25,D,27,,8
```

Comment: The output is incorrect, or else the input is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/\s*$//' -e 's/^\([^,]*,[^,]*,\)*[^,]*,[^,]*$/&,/' -e 's/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),/\2,\1,/g'
```

For example,

```
$ sed -e 's/^\([^,]*,[^,]*,\)*[^,]*,[^,]*$/&,/' -e 's/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),/\2,\1,/g' <<EOF
23,A,49,B,2,C
25,B,27,D,8,
EOF

A,23,B,49,C,2,
B,25,D,27,,8,
```

Explanation:

- `s/\s*$//` gets rid of any whitespace characters at the end of the line.
- `s/^\([^,]*,[^,]*,\)*[^,]*,[^,]*$/&,/` appends a comma if there are an odd number of commas on the line.

  - `\([^,]*,[^,]*,\)*` is a group of something-not-comm comma something-not-comma comma, repeated 0 or more times, followed by
  - `[^,]*,[^,]*` is something-not-comma coma followed by optional non-commas
- `s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),/\2,\1,/g` swaps comma-delimited fields